# The meaning of 'but' here

Tags: word-meaning

> Max smiled indulgently. He blew on his coffee. "Around the corner he
>   goes to Moe's barbershop and plunk goes the whole ten-spot on a filly
>   named Miss Sparks running in the fifth at Belmont. On the nose, ***but***.
>   And you guessed it, MacDonald, Miss Sparks comes in and pays eleven to
>   one.
>
> -The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler -

What is the meaning of '***but***' here? however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I would say that this is an uncommon usage of the "but" when it has a contrastive meaning "though".

[Here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=119)
 is an article on final conjunctions.